# Android - 2-ways USB sync for multiple calendars from outlook 2013 to phone

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, sync, usb, calendar, outlook

I use an iPhone since 5 years, and I'd like to switch to an Android phone, under KitKat and probably soon Lollipop.
I've checked all my needs and there is still one for wich I didn't find how to satisfy it with an Android phone, the reason I ask for your help : syncing calendars and contacts.

With iTunes until now, I connect the phone, click on "Sync" and the work is done flawlessly, even with many or strange entries in my calendars. Perfect job.  I'm searching the same kind of working on an Android phone.

I use Outlook 2013 x64 on a Windows 7 x64 system. It's my main database for both my calendars and contacts. Note that I WON'T switch to an online solution.

I have 3 calendars into that Outlook, lets says they are called C1 (personal), C2 (professional) and C3 (family).
Into these calendars, I have many years of events, and multiple kind of events : recurring, multi-days, full day events, events with alarms, recurring events that start on 1900 (cause I don't know the right year for them).
Note : I don't use the category feature of events.

I found 2 apps on Android that seems to satisfy my needs : BusinessCalendar and Digical.
There may be other ones but I've found these that do the job like I want.

At this step, I still need to find a software that can make a 2-ways sync between each of these calendars by direct USB connection (why not by bluetooth even if I prefer avoiding it, but sure not Wi-Fi).
But all I've found so far as softwares can join C1, C2 and C3 into a single calendar C(phone) onto the phone.
Or better, sync individually each of these C1 C2 C3 from Outlook to C1(phone) C2(phone) C3(phone) onto the phone.
But I found nothing that is able to sync back the same way C1(phone), C2(phone) and C3(phone) from the phone to their C1 C2 C3 equivalent into Outlook.

I've tested without fibnding what I need :

- MyPhoneExplorer (do not deal old dates correctly, and do not seem to be able to sync back individually each of the calendars)
- CompanionLink (do not manage multi-days events)
- Android-Sync
- Mobisynapse (awfull results)
- Android PC Sync
- myDesktop Companion
- Akruto
- VCOrganizer
- Sync2 (not a solution for the exposed problem)
- Samsung Kies (not tested, I don't have a Samsung phone for testing)
- HTC solution (not tested, I don't have a HTC phone for testing)
- Could not try The Missing Sync because it do not offert a trial version. By the way, the feedback about this soft seems to be very bad.

I cannot buy many phones just to test the proprietary solutions from Samsung or HTC.
I cannot take the risk to corrupt my Outlook databases just to test the multiples available solutions and discover some day that it has been corrupted, so I've never done a real reverse sync : I've just deduced the way of working of these software from looking at their options that are so far clear enough to deduce what they are going to do on a sync.

So I ask for your experience (and not just thoughts) :
Do you experienced one or many softwares that allow to do a reliable 2-way sync from my Outlook contacts and multiple calendars from the PC to contacts and multiple calendars onto the phone ? Price is not a problem if the software is reliable and do not exceed 100 euros.

2 main constraints :
I DON'T want my calendar to go onto the net.
I don't mind if my contacts go onto gmail, but Outlook must stay my main database.

Note :
The answer "This does not exist" is a hearable answer, that would of course force me to continue with the iPhone, but... that's life. But I hope I missed some kind of software that would allow me to make the switch, ideally without needing to be prisoner of a brand.

Answer (score 0):

> I have 3 calendars into that Outlook, lets says they are called C1
>   (personal), C2 (professional) and C3 (family). Into these calendars, I
>   have many years of events, and multiple kind of events : recurring,
>   multi-days, full day events, events with alarms, recurring events that
>   start on 1900 (cause I don't know the right year for them). Note : I
>   don't use the category feature of events.

CompanionLink can do this. You will need to use their Android app (DejaOffice) to hold Outlook data on the phone. You will do USB sync for C1-C3 to DejaOffice Calendar. While this still merges all Outlook Calendars in one calendar in DejaOffice, C1, C2, and C3 are denoted as Categories in DejaOffice Calendar so you can easily filter and see appointments for each. If you create an appointment on the phone and assign it to the C2 Category in DejaOffice, it will sync back to Outlook's C2 Calendar. USB sync is supported. This works for Contacts + Calendar (and Tasks and Notes if you wish). Multi-day events are fully supported; not sure why you got the impression that they aren't...?

Link: http://www.companionlink.com/android/outlook/

Disclosure: I work for CompanionLink, and this kind of setup is a common one we deal with.

Comment: Hello, Thank you for your answer. I will give CL another try. My first one was did not sync a multi day event, but perhaps a bad configuration... Let's give a second chance. The problem is that I may have pass the evaluation date limit.

Comment: A question : will I be able to use another calendar app on the phone than the DejaOffice one and still have this 2-ways sync work ?

Answer (score 0):

Another option syncs over Wi-Fi rather than USB because it is automatic. Try [AkrutoSync](http://www.akruto.com) (www.akruto.com). Does not sync with the cloud and works with all compatible devices for no extra charge.